# node-canvas and jpeg build dependencies on OSX

Tags: node.js, canvas, osx-snow-leopard, libjpeg, build-dependencies

I'm using node canvas to generate PNG images of HTML5 generated canvas (using [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com)). I installed it using:

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig npm install canvas
```

When the canvas contains only PNG images, node-canvas renders the output image just fine. However, if the canvas also has JPEG images embedded, it raises an exception and quits:

```
/Users/sa125/node_modules/fabric/dist/all.js:14238
      ctx.drawImage(
          ^
Error: Image given has not completed loading
    at klass.fabric.Image.fabric.util.createClass._render (/Users/sa125/node_modules/fabric/dist/all.js:14238:11)
    at klass.fabric.Image.fabric.util.createClass.render (/Users/sa125/node_modules/fabric/dist/all.js:14108:12)
    at extend._draw (/Users/sa125/node_modules/fabric/dist/all.js:6001:16)
    at extend.renderAll (/Users/sa125/node_modules/fabric/dist/all.js:6147:16)
    at extend.insertAt (/Users/sa125/node_modules/fabric/dist/all.js:6052:37)
    at fabric.util.object.extend._enlivenObjects (/Users/sa125/node_modules/fabric/dist/all.js:8950:15)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at fabric.util.object.extend._enlivenObjects (/Users/sa125/node_modules/fabric/dist/all.js:8949:24)
    at onLoaded (/Users/sa125/node_modules/fabric/dist/all.js:2082:11)
    at /Users/sa125/node_modules/fabric/dist/all.js:2101:11
```

This is not a fabric issue, since when running the same canvas generator on Ubuntu linux, all images come out fine (both JPEG and PNG)

So basically this is a dependency issue - any idea what I need to `brew install` to get this working? I've already installed libjpeg, as well as pango, cairo,  pixbuf, etc. However, I had to install node-canvas using the above PKG_CONFIG since anything else would break the installation, possibly due to how homebrew handled some of the linking. thanks.